# NullPointerException при обращении к 0 элементу инициализированного массива

Tags: java

Взял тут в руки книжку (Кен Арнольд, Джеймс Гослинг - Язык программирования JAVA), и застрял в самом начале.

Задачка выглядит так:

> Упражнение 1.9
>
> Измените приложение Fibonacci так, чтобы числа Фибоначчи сохранялись в массиве. Для
> этого создайте новый класс для хранения самого числа и логического значения,
> являющегося признаком четности, после чего создайте массив для ссылок на объекты
> этого класса.

Попытался реализовать:

```
public class Fibonacci {
static final int MAX_NUMBERS = 10;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    FibonacciItem[] fibonacciItems = new FibonacciItem[MAX_NUMBERS];
    fibonacciItems[0].number = 1;

    //more code...
}

class FibonacciItem {
    public int number = 1;

    public boolean is_even() {
        return this.number % 2 == 0;
    }
}

}
```

И внезапно расстроился, получив NullPointerException на строке

```
fibonacciItems[0].number = 1;
```

Кроме того, IDEA любезно подсвечивает предыдущую строку сообщением

> Contents of array "fibonacciItems" are read, but newer written to ...

Подскажите, что происходит?

Comment: ты инициализировал массив, но ты его не заполнил

Comment: Так вот, я вроде пытаюсь его заполнить..

Comment: Или надо писать что-то вроде fibonacciItems[0] = new FibonacciItem()?

Comment: нет, ты пытаешься у нулевого элемента массива в поле number записать 1. Но в этом индексе нет объекта FibonacciItem, чтобы к нему обратиться

Comment: `Или надо писать что-то вроде fibonacciItems[0] = new FibonacciItem()?` - да. именно так. чтобы в каждую ячейку положить по экземпляру....вручную 10 раз или в цикле. а только потом можно манипулировать данными в ячейках

Comment: Ага.. Кажется что-то понял.. new в строке инициализации массива получается даже не пытается создавать объекты?

Comment: Да. `FibonacciItem[] fibonacciItems = new FibonacciItem[MAX_NUMBERS];` - ты  всего лишь говоришь, что у тебя  `fibonacciItems` будет массивом размером `MAX_NUMBERS` с типом `FibonacciItem` (содержащий объекты с типом FibonacciItem). всё......... но при этом массив, как и любой другой надо заполнить.

Comment: Можешь тогда перенести комментарии в ответ, или так закрыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как тебе уже сказали тебе нужно инициализировать каждый объект из созданного массива перед его использованием. Просто создай цикл такого вида:

```html
for(int i = 0; i < fibonnaciItems.length(); i++) {
  fibonnaciItems[i] = new FibonnaciItem();
}
```

и дальше делай с ним что хочешь.